# Display data from the database

Tags: mysql, laravel-5

I am trying to display data from my database on a table.
when the user register, he select a `course_name` from a select field from a 
register view.

Here is the code:

```
<div class="form-group">
{!!Form::label('course_1',' Course 1')!!}
{!!Form::select('course_1',App\Models\Course::lists('course_name','id'),'',!!}
</div>
```

postulant_view:

```
@foreach($postulant as $p)
     <td>{{$course->where('id',$p->course_1)->select('course_name')->first()}}</td>
@endforeach
```

Controller:

```
$postulant = Postulant::all();
$course = new Course();
$title = 'Liste des postulants';
return view('admin/list_postulants','postulant'=>$postulant,'title'=>$title,'course'=>$course]);
```

But I don't know why I get this on the table: `{"course_name":"English"}`

Comment: You are getting course_name, because you are selecting it. What supposed to be in the view ?

Comment: @user4621032 Only English. course_name is just a field on a course table, English is a data on that table. I don't know why i get this output :{"course_name":"English"} on the browser

Comment: $course->where('id',$p->course_1)->select('course_name')->first()->course_name

Comment: Actually the query should be in controller and only variables should be passed to the view

Comment: thanks a lot @user4621032, it's working...

Comment: @user4621032 you can post that as answer, I will vote for it.

Answer (score 0):

The following code works

```
$course->where('id',$p->course_1)
    ->select('course_name')
    ->first()
    ->course_name
```

Comment: Could you please [edit] in an explanation of why this code answers the question? Code-only answers are [discouraged](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/148272/274165), because they don't teach the solution.